# Как изменить пути подключаемых файлов после переноса wordpress на новый домен?

Tags: wordpress

В конфиге прописал новый адрес сайте, в базе данных (wp_options) данных тоже изменил. После первой загрузки страницы значение в БД переписывается на старое значение.

Что может являться причиной?

Comment: Причина в неправильном переносе сайта. Почитайте, как делать это правильно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Воспользовался одним из плагинов. Урлы постов, страниц, меню работают, как надо, урлы верные. Но подключаемые css файлы по-прежнему подключены в header через старый адрес сайта.

Comment: скорее всего, пути css прибиты гвоздями в коде header.php

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаете [плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/), с его помощью создаёте резервную копию. Это всё на старом месте. Затем на новом хостинге разворачиваете эту резервную копию и все абсолютные пути - включающие в себя домен - будут автоматически изменены на новые.